# How to lock/unlock android devices using unity and c#?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, screen-lock

I looked all over the internet for a solution for a few days but couldn't find one that would help me lock/unlock an android device using unity programmatically. Mostly all the solutions are using android studio. Can some help me out please?

Comment: Hmm... unlock the device? You need the password for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create library that will help you to use Android's native featues like toast and notifications

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Vishwajeet.